# Objective C: Error when trying to initialize instance of CLLocation

Tags: objective-c, ios, cllocation

I am hitting an error (program crashed) when it hits the following code

```
CLLocation *userLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithCoordinate:locationManager.location.coordinate];
```

I tried to replace the argument with the following and I get the same error as well

```
CLLocation *userLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithCoordinate:mapView.userLocation.coordinate];
```

Can anyone advise me on what should be the correct argument to use here for the user's current location?

Thanks!

Zhen

Stacktrace:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CLLocation initWithCoordinate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e0620'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html), `CLLocation` does not have an initializer called `initWithCoordinate:`. Use one of the following:

- `initWithLatitude:longitude:`
- `initWithCoordinate:altitude:horizontalAccuracy:verticalAccuracy:timestamp:`
- `initWithCoordinate:altitude:horizontalAccuracy:verticalAccuracy:course:speed:timestamp:`

Comment: Yeap, thanks for the correction. My mistake. It's working now. Thanks!